# How nest Select statement

Tags: sql-server

I have select like this:

```
  SELECT UserName FROM Users WHERE userId= @UserId;
```

I want to get this value and use as register into insert

I try:

```
INSERT INTO Product.ProductDetail VALUES (
SELECT UserName FROM Users WHERE userId= @UserId;
    );
```

but I get invalid column, how is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect. The proper way does not have `VALUES` keyword in `INSERT INTO...SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO Product.ProductDetail (ColumnName) -- Must specify target column if you have multiple columns in the table
SELECT UserName 
FROM Users 
WHERE userId= @UserId
```

Comment: and what about if I have more than one value in insert like `VALUES (IDENT_CURRENT('Store.Cart'),@ProductId,` and third parameter is my select?

Comment: you can still have it in the *SELECT* clause: `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Store.Cart'), @ProductId, UserName ...`

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT INTO Product.ProductDetail (UserName)
SELECT UserName FROM Users WHERE userId= @UserId`

You'll need to specific insert column names if you have auto increment key in your table to be inserted.